# Copying PHP variables to the clipboard with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to copy values generated using a `foreach` loop to the clipboard using `JS`. Only the first row gets copied, no matter which row is clicked.

Here is the code producing the values to be copied:

```
foreach($results_array as $value) {
    /*Some PHP code*/ 
    <input class="col-sm-10" title="Copy Link" type="text" id="copy_this" value='<?php echo  $user_folder."/".$value; ?>' onclick="copyTo()"/>
}
```

My JS function:

```
function copyTo() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("copy_this");
                                
  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole purpose of IDs is to uniquely IDentify an element. Also, that's not how `execCommand()` works (how can your code possibly know that text you want copied?).

Getting rid of IDs (which you don't really need at all) you could do something like:

```js
function copyTo(input) {
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="First" onclick="copyTo(this)">
<input type="text" value="Second" onclick="copyTo(this)">
<input type="text" value="Third" onclick="copyTo(this)">
```